# Node -> Cocoa app data flow

Tags: javascript, cocoa, node.js, design-patterns, cocoa-bindings

I have a question about comunication between node server and client cocoa app.
I need to send every three seconds message from my server to specific clients.

And I really dont know how to do that. Have you any ideas?
(WebSockets arent probably best way (its cococa)??)

Thanks!

Comment: have you seen socketio-cocoa? maybe it can help: https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa

Comment: Thats perfect!!! Exactly what i needed.